# The reducer updates apposArrayProp but Redux doesn't update my view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm newbie with Redux and I want to update the array **this.props.apposArrayProp** after calling the API, but I'm stuck, the action and the reducer are executed but the view doesn't change no matter what. I don't know if I need mapDispatchToProps in the connect method.

My actions.js file

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

export const RECEIVE_APPOS   = 'RECEIVE_APPOS'

export function fetchAppos(appo_id) {
  console.log('in fetchAppos 148')
    return dispatch => {
      return fetch('/appointments/get_appos')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(json => dispatch(receiveAppos(json)))
 }
}

function receiveAppos(apposArrayProp) {
  console.log('receiveAppos Action>>>>>'+JSON.stringify(apposArrayProp))
  return {
    type:  RECEIVE_APPOS,
    apposArrayProp
  }
}
```

The reducer file, appointments_Rdcer.js:

```
import { fetchAppos, RECEIVE_APPOS } from '../actions/actions'

const initialState = {
  apposArrayProp: []
}
const appointments_Rdcer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_APPOS:
      console.log('RECEIVE_APPOS REDUCER >>>'+
     JSON.stringify(action.apposArrayProp))
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
            apposArrayProp: action.apposArrayProp
        })

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default appointments_Rdcer
```

Finally my Container.js file:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { ReactDom } from 'react-dom'
import * as ApposActionCreators from '../actions/actions'

class ApposComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('In componentDidMount'+JSON.stringify(this.props))
    let action = ApposActionCreators.fetchAppos()
    this.props.dispatch(action)
  }
  render() {
    var tempo = ''
    var trNodes = this.props.apposArrayProp.map(function (appo) {
      tempo += appo.petname
      console.log('##  I want to see this #####' + tempo)
    })
    return (
      <div className="appoList">Display {tempo} </div>
    )
  }
}

ApposComponent.propTypes = {
  apposArrayProp: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

ApposComponent.defaultProps = {
   apposArrayProp:  []
 }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    apposArrayProp: state.apposArrayProp
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ApposComponent)
```

Versions: 
"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-redux": "^4.4.0",
"redux": "^3.3.1",

I see changes in the log:

[image: React redux]

**SOLVED**

¡Dave Walsh!, ¡Muchas gracias!

I changed my reducer from:

```
export default function rootReducer(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    appointments: appointments_Rdcer(state.appointments_Rdcer, action)
  }
}
```

to:

```
export default function rootReducer(state = {}, action) {
  return {
   appointments_Rdcer: appointments_Rdcer(state.appointments_Rdcer, action)
}
```

}

And followed your advice and now all is working as a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapStateToProps` function should look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    apposArrayProp: state.appointments_Rdcer.apposArrayProp
  };
};
```

That should be enough to get it working.

Additionally, I'd also encourage you to take a look at your render logic. You're using `Array#map` like it's `Array#forEach`. What you have will still work, but it's kind of ugly.